# Can't click on href link using Watir and Xpath

Tags: ruby, xpath, watir

I am trying to click all the links within a table.
The xpath is below.

```
(2..lines).each do |i|
  browser.element(:xpath => "//*[@id=\"StmtSummaryForm:stmtDataTabletbody0\"]/tr[{i}]/td[3]/a").click
end
```

However, I get

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `click' for #<Watir::HTMLElementCollection:0x00007fcfa69d3c08>
```

I assume my xpath is wrong, or I'm using watir incorrectly.

PRY:

```
[61] pry(main)> elements = @browser.elements(:xpath => "//*[@id=\"StmtSummaryForm:stmtDataTabletbody0\"]/tr[2]/td[3]/a")
=> #<Watir::HTMLElementCollection:0x00007fcfa7424130
 @query_scope=#<Watir::Browser:0x..f0106c8d0f94f382 url="https://personal.domain.com/us/Statements" title="Statements">,
 @selector={:xpath=>"//*[@id=\"StmtSummaryForm:stmtDataTabletbody0\"]/tr[2]/td[3]/a"},
 @selector_builder=
  #<Watir::Locators::Element::SelectorBuilder:0x00007fcfa6b8fb78
   @built={:xpath=>"//*[@id=\"StmtSummaryForm:stmtDataTabletbody0\"]/tr[2]/td[3]/a"},
   @custom_attributes=[],
   @query_scope=#<Watir::Browser:0x..f0106c8d0f94f382 url="https://personal.domain.com/us/Statements" title="Statements">,
   @selector={:xpath=>"//*[@id=\"StmtSummaryForm:stmtDataTabletbody0\"]/tr[2]/td[3]/a"},
   @valid_attributes=
    [:title,
     :lang,
     :dir,
     :dataset,
     :accesskey,
     :accessKey,
     :innertext,
     :innerText,
     :onabort,
     :onblur,
     :oncancel,
     :oncanplay,
     :oncanplaythrough,
     :onchange,
     :onclick,
     :onclose,
     :oncuechange,
     :ondblclick,
     :ondrag,
     :ondragend,
     :ondragenter,
     :ondragexit,
     :ondragleave,
     :ondragover,
     :ondragstart,
     :ondrop,
     :ondurationchange,
     :onemptied,
```

I also tried:

```
[68] pry(main)> elements = @browser.elements(:xpath => "//*[@id=\"StmtSummaryForm:stmtDataTabletbody0\"]/tr[2]/node()").links
/Users/aa/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.7.1/gems/pry-0.12.2/lib/pry/exceptions.rb:28: warning: $SAFE will become a normal global variable in Ruby 3.0
NoMethodError: undefined method `links' for #<Watir::HTMLElementCollection:0x00007fcfa744e610>
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't get an `HTMLElementCollection` error if you are using `browser.element`.

Watir is designed to reduce reliance on XPath in general.
It can get complicated if the clicks reload the page; especially if the reload might have a different structure. Regardless, this *should work:

```
table = browser.table(id: "StmtSummaryForm:stmtDataTabletbody0")
table.links.each(&:click)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `click` on collections `elements`, collection doesn't have click method. You have to iterate the collection and then have to click one after another.

Write this code

```
browser.table(id: "StmtSummaryForm:stmtDataTabletbody0").rows.each do |row|
  row.cell(index: 2).link.click
end
```

It will click the link which is on the third column of the table. WATIR automatically calculates the total number of rows in the table, you don't have to specify the count explicitly like you have done.